# 'Hasfocus' and chrome

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using hasfocus to enforce focus to a specific element like this

```
this.inputHasFocus = ko.observable();
this.forceInputFocus = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return false;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this.inputHasFocus(true);
    }
}, this);
```

inputHasFocus is bound to hasfocus on the input that i want to force focus to, and forceInputFocus is bound to all other elements that I dont want to steal the focus from the input.

Please, try this fiddle in Firefox and it works (Press the Arrow button and the input is focused)
http://jsfiddle.net/AWHhr/2/

Try it Chrome and it does not, the write method isnt triggered when pressing the arrow button. Whats wrong? Any better way of fixing this?

Src code, relevant code start at line 94 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js

edit: Isolated problem http://jsfiddle.net/ygCEs/2

Comment: Maybe try to repro what you are after as simple as possible outside of your library. I also wasn't sure what I was looking for in Firefox vs. Chrome using the arrow key.

Comment: True, done. I was afraid it would work in a simple fiddle but it didnt so thats good :D See edit

Comment: In Chrome, clicking on a button does not give it focus and does not fire focus events. You might have to handle as part of click.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZxtTp/

Comment: Ok, the initial problem is that if the textbox isnt focues the keyboard shortcuts for the combobox wont fire, maybe theres a more elegant soluton than trying to get the input in focus, also, if the button is in focus and you press enter to select a item in the dropdown the click event on the button will fire and reopen the dropdown right after it was closed

Comment: Hmm, maybe just a special click binding that also blurs the button, will have to test if the keyboard events still fires though

Comment: Fixed it by manually calling a force focus method on all places that can steal focus. A bit ugly but it works